# Using external library variable in app.component.ts file in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular6

I want to use the global variable *cwic* declared in an external js library in the app.component.ts file. The js library in kept in the assets folder as cwic-debug.js. Now to initialize the library and use the cwic variable the statement SystemController method must be called as-

```
cwic.SystemController.initialize()
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/cwic-debug.js"></script>
```

I have tried initializing the cwic library in the following manner-

**app.component.ts-**

```
 export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    cwic.SystemController.initialize();
    console.log(cwic);
  }
  title = 'Angular Project';
}
```

But since cwic variable in not recogized it throws up an error and underlines the cwic word in red.

The js library i.e. **cwic-debug.js** looks something like this-

```
var cwic =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
```

How can I use this *cwic* variable in app.component.ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the variable and type it as `any`.

```
declare var cwic: any;
```

TypeScript will then stop to complain about the type of the variable and just assume it exists, but you will no longer get type helps from your IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped! But is there any other way around of importing the cwic variable into the app.component.ts file?

Comment: I don't exaclty know what cwic is, but if the library is just injected into the JS domain, probably not. You can look up if the library provides typescript typing files (*.d.ts), which just contain type annotations for typescript, you could then import those.